# DynamoDB exception after adding Map<Long, String> attribute

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to modify an existing DynamoDB table to add a column which is a simple Map<Long, String> however once I add the column and try to set it I get the following error:

```
 com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted
```

Added the following to the class representing the dynamo object:

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "orderIdToBillingDate")
private Map<Long, String> orderIdToBillingDate;

public Map<Long, String> getOrderIdToBillingDate() {
    return orderIdToBillingDate;
}

public void setOrderIdToBillingDate(final Map<Long, String> orderIdToBillingDate) {
    this.orderIdToBillingDate = orderIdToBillingDate;
}
```

Is dynamo not capable of handling a simple map of Long to String?  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDBMapper will handle a Map OK. If your Map contains fields which are not primitives, you would need to provide a converter. In your case, Long and String are [considered primitives](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html) and it should work fine without any additional annotations or converters.

I have `Map<String, BigDecimal>` and `Map<String, String>` in my application and they work just fine.

To be honest, I'm pretty sure that error is unrelated to the Map you have posted in your question. I think you have another field which is the problem.